# Why does the debug report logs "Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed" on clicking a spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-spinner

I am using a List with ArrayAdapter for the spinner. But on selecting the spinner, the W/InputEventReceiver logs that the input event receiver has already been disposed

The adapter works fine when created with the method .createFromResource() and a static Array of string, but does not seem to work with the List of Strings.

This is My Activity Code

```
package club.bms.keshav.readersreserve;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TempActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private List<CharSequence> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private static final String TAG = "TempActivity";
    private String temp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp);
        userList.clear();
        DatabaseReference rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        rootReference.child(ConstantFields.DATABASE_USER_LIST).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            String temp;
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    temp = dataSnapshot1.child(ConstantFields.DATABASE_USER_NAME).getValue(String.class);
                    userList.add(temp);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tempSpinner);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setPrompt("SELECT THE CURRENT HOLDER OF THE BOOK");
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Adapter Set");
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemSelected: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onNothingSelected: ");
    }
}
```

None of the log statements get printed in the itemselectedlistener methods.
This is the log statement that gets printed on clicking the spinner.

```
W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

The spinner just expands on clicking.

[Before Clicking the Spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Dht.png)

[After Clicking the Spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAyo5.png)

Comment: provide the code you are using

Comment: The code in the activity is the code itself

Comment: your code is absolutely working fine... you just need to notify your adapter when you get the database from firebase. Also dont forget to check if adapter is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rootReference.child(ConstantFields.DATABASE_USER_LIST).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        String temp;
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                temp = dataSnapshot1.child(ConstantFields.DATABASE_USER_NAME).getValue(String.class);
                userList.add(temp);
               if(adapter!=null){
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine thank you. But do we need to call notifyDataSetChanged(), after every addition or would it work the same if call this method outside the loop?

Comment: It works the same if i notify the adapter after the formation of the list.